Symfony returns error message "this type has been excluded in "config/services.yaml"
I'm trying to show the database table, i'm using the following composer and twig:
private $doctrine;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_signal_index', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(Request $request, Signal $signal): Response
    {
        $priority = $request->query->get('priority');
        $contributor = $request->query->get('contributor');
        $status = $request->query->get('status');
        $transition = null;
        $resolution = null;
    
        if ($priority !== null) {
            $transition = $this->doctrine->getRepository(TransitionSignal::class)->findBy(['transition' => $priority]);
        }
    
        if ($contributor !== null) {
            $transition = $this->doctrine->getRepository(TransitionSignal::class)->findBy(['transition' => $contributor]);
        }
    
        if ($status !== null) {
            $resolution = $this->doctrine->getRepository(ResolutionSignal::class)->findBy(['resolution' => $status]);
        }
    
        return $this->render('signal/index.html.twig', [
            'signal' => $signal,
            'transition' => $transition,
            'resolution' => $resolution,
        ]);

in twig:
{% for signal in signals %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{ signal.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ signal.date ? signal.date|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') : '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ signal.address }}</td>
        <td>{{ signal.description }}</td>
        <td>{{ transition.priority }}</td>
        <td>{{ transition.contributor }}</td>
        <td>{{ resolution.actionPlanStatus }}</td>

            <td>
                <div class="mt-3">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                        <a href="{{ path('app_signal_show', {'id': signal.id}) }}" class="btn btn-secondary" role="button">show</a>
                        <a href="{{ path('app_signal_edit', {'id': signal.id}) }}" class="btn btn-secondary" role="button">edit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="26">no records found</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}

The server is returning the following error message:
Cannot autowire argument $signal of "App\Controller\SignalController::index()": it needs an instance of "App\Entity\Signal" but this type has been excluded in "config/services.yaml".
I'm expecting to show the table from database

This is quite a simple answer. You are trying to autowire the Signal entity into your route function. The default Symfony dependency injection (which is used to autowire your dependencies) is configured to exclude some classes. Typically it looks like this in your config/services.yaml
services: 

    # Some other config

    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

That means that your Entities are not autowired by the framework.
This has a simple fix in your usecase however. When injecting the entity in your route, you should provide som information about how to retrieve the entity using  the EntityValueResolver. You can learn about it here, just be sure to switch to your exact Symfony version.
You should then modify your route, to include some information abou how the entity should be fetched. Lets suppose, you want to fetch the entity by ID.
The route would look like this
    #[Route('/{id}', name: 'app_signal_index', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(Request $request, Signal $signal): Response
    {
        $priority = $request->query->get('priority');
        $contributor = $request->query->get('contributor');
        $status = $request->query->get('status');
        $transition = null;
        $resolution = null;
    
        if ($priority !== null) {
            $transition = $this->doctrine->getRepository(TransitionSignal::class)->findBy(['transition' => $priority]);
        }
    
        if ($contributor !== null) {
            $transition = $this->doctrine->getRepository(TransitionSignal::class)->findBy(['transition' => $contributor]);
        }
    
        if ($status !== null) {
            $resolution = $this->doctrine->getRepository(ResolutionSignal::class)->findBy(['resolution' => $status]);
        }
    
        return $this->render('signal/index.html.twig', [
            'signal' => $signal,
            'transition' => $transition,
            'resolution' => $resolution,
        ]);
    }

If you want to fetch the whole table of Signals, like you said in the question, you must remove the Signal parameter from your route function and fetch the desired entity using your Repository inside the function. Also note that your variables that you are passing into Twig have different names in your template and your route (signal vs signals)
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_signal_index', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {
        $signals = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Signal::class)->findAll();
        $priority = $request->query->get('priority');
        $contributor = $request->query->get('contributor');
        $status = $request->query->get('status');
        $transition = null;
        $resolution = null;
    
        if ($priority !== null) {
            $transition = $this->doctrine->getRepository(TransitionSignal::class)->findBy(['transition' => $priority]);
        }
    
        if ($contributor !== null) {
            $transition = $this->doctrine->getRepository(TransitionSignal::class)->findBy(['transition' => $contributor]);
        }
    
        if ($status !== null) {
            $resolution = $this->doctrine->getRepository(ResolutionSignal::class)->findBy(['resolution' => $status]);
        }
    
        return $this->render('signal/index.html.twig', [
            'signals' => $signals,
            'transition' => $transition,
            'resolution' => $resolution,
        ]);
    }

Your example is a little strange, I could not understand correctly what are you trying to accomplish. But it seems that you want to print out every signal in the database and include related transition signals? If you want more advice, please provide some information about the use case.
One other thing I would like to point out, is that instead of injecting Doctrine in your controller, you should separate the logic into a service class and inject that into the controller. Or at least inject the desired repositories, which then provides more type safety inside your code. You can use the contructor and constructor property promotion (if you are using PHP 8 or above) to do this
   public function __construct(
      private TransitionSignalRepository $transitionSignalRepository,
      private ResolutionSignalRepository $resolutionSignalRepository,
   ) {}

Instead of doing $this->doctrine->getRepository(TransitionSignal::class)->findBy(['transition' => $priority]); you just call $this->transitionSignalRepository->findBy(['transition' => $priority]);.
